# pstricks margin with rput when putting an image

Tags: graphics, pstricks

I want to do the following:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{document}    
\begin{pspicture}(2in, 1in)
    \psframe[linecolor=red, fillcolor=red, fillstyle=solid, dimen=outer](0, 0)(1, 1)
    \psframe[linecolor=black, fillcolor=black, fillstyle=solid, dimen=outer](1, 0)(2, 1)
\end{pspicture}    
\end{document}
```

and obtained what I wanted as follows:

[image: main-psframe]

However, for some reason, I want an external image for the black square. Well, this is what I created for a black square image:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\psset{unit=1in}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}(1in, 1in)
    \psframe[linecolor=black, fillcolor=black, fillstyle=solid, dimen=outer](0, 0)(1, 1)
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

saved it as `blacksquare.pdf`. Then, when I did the following:

```
\documentclass[pstricks]{standalone}
\psset{unit=1in}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(2in, 1in)
    \psframe[linecolor=red, fillcolor=red, fillstyle=solid, dimen=outer](0, 0)(1, 1)
    \rput[lb](1,0){\includegraphics{blacksquare}}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

The result is:

[image: main-rput]

There is a slight white line in the middle. Where does that margin come from and how can I remove it?

File List as requested:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2012/09/15 v1.1b Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
ifluatex.sty    2010/03/01 v1.3 Provides the ifluatex switch (HO)
   ifpdf.sty    2011/01/30 v2.3 Provides the ifpdf switch (HO)
 ifxetex.sty    2010/09/12 v0.6 Provides ifxetex conditional
 xkeyval.sty    2014/12/03 v2.7a package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2012/09/15 v1.1b Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
pstricks.sty    2013/12/12 v0.60 LaTeX wrapper for `PSTricks' (RN,HV)
pstricks.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PSTricks' (tvz,hv)
pst-xkey.tex    2005/11/25 v1.6 PSTricks specialization of xkeyval (HA)
  pst-fp.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60 `PST-fp' (hv)
  xcolor.sty    2007/01/21 v2.11 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
   xetex.def    2015/03/25 v4.04 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (TeX Liv
e/RRM/JK)
graphicx.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0g Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2014/10/28 v1.0p Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2010/04/23 v1.9 graphics configuration of TeX Live
blacksquare.pdf    Graphic file (type QTm)
 ***********
```

Comment: Does it persist upon zooming in?

Comment: @Werner Yes. Zooming-in does not change the issue.

Comment: I cannot see it with an up-to-date TeXLive. Put `\listfiles` as first line into your document and send the file list (at the end of the log file)

Comment: @Herbert I added the file list.

Comment: `pstricks.tex    2014/10/25 v2.60` is really old.  Current version is 2.65

Comment: @Herbert You're right. I updated it and now the problem is solved.